# Handling pressure and stress in an inescapable position?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, management, time-management

I am currently working as a software developer and I feel that my work load is too heavy.

To make this problem worse my supervisor asks me to finish everything in a day when the amount of work I have will take longer than that because I have so much to do. When I inevitably fail he tries to make me stay at work past the end of the working day to finish my tasks.

On top of this if I do take a days holiday then I am instead asked to work on the weekend to make up the lost time.

I am unable to leave this company because I signed into a  bond for 1 year.

There is couple of months left to finish the 1 year but I am really struggling.

Is there anything I can do that will make these last few months more bearable for myself, or a potential compromise I could offer to my supervisor?

Comment: Hello vicky, and welcome back to the Workplace. Questions that get the best answers ask questions that inspire [*why* and *how* answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Right now your question isn't very clear about what you're asking -- I can only see ranting about your position, not an actual problem you are looking for a solution to. Could you please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/14222/edit) your post to bring it in to line with our [site guidelines](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: hi @jmac I edited my ques

Comment: Thanks for the edit vicky, I understand the situation a lot better now. Unfortunately, it looks like you're asking a legal question which is off-topic -- we can't give you advice on what will happen if you break your contract, and we can't wave a magic wand and make enduring the last 2 months until it ends any easier.

Comment: @vicky, try to be more specific. Tell what exactly troubles you (boss accusing unfairly, unrespectful coworkers, etc.). Right now there is no actual problem visible but the one that you cannot leave because of your contract, as jmac mentioned.

Comment: Hi @vicky i took the liberty of editing this into a question that focusses on methods to deal with the stress and pressures of the workplace more than the original rant / legal question it could have been. Hopefully this will still give you constructive answers for your situation. I wish you luck!

Comment: Part 1: A point that I make in various forums is that there are (in the United States) about 2 million programmers and 500 million programmable machines (Desktops, Laptops, Servers, Smartphones, etc.).  Therefore there is far more that needs to be done than there are people to do it.  I have seen hints (keyword search 'What's wrong with Indian IT?') that the ratio of competent computer programmers in India to the overall workforce is twice as bad compared to the entire workforce - I don't know how that adds up on a per device basis.

Comment: Part 2: Your supervisor isn't paying any attention to you.  For them to be leaning on you like this in the first place means they think they have a 'captive'.  All you can do until the contract runs out is plug away - when it runs out take a break.  Do no show up the next Monday ready for more abuse. Spend a couple of weeks relaxing, and thinking about what you want to do next.  If alternative employment is available, explore it, but don't commit while you're under duress.

Comment: Part 3: Questions elsewhere indicate that departing employees in India need 'letters of recommendation' and in some cases these are withheld.  If these people don't want you to leave they may make your departure difficult.  If they're doing this then you're in an interesting negotiating position - you should be able to demand better terms.  The first thing to ask for is a 'normal workweek', the second is to ask for a different boss, particularly one who respects you and who you trust.

Comment: Indian companies are **CHEAP** . What better did you expect ? **:)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For this answer I am going to assume that you are legally tied in to the position and have no way of removing yourself from the situation. This answer will therefore be tailored for how you can best prepare yourself to get through the next couple of months.*

**Services for dealing with stress**

Quite a few companies, depending on where you are, have an agreement with a third party company that help deal with difficult situations. Whether this is stress, grief, anger, sadness etc.

It might be worth your time investigating if this is something your company offers. If you are unsure you can always ask HR. If your company does not offer this kind of service then it might be worth your time to investigate counselling yourself.

Stress can have very serious effects on your health, especially prolonged stress, and this can have strong ramifications on both your physical and mental well-being. If you are ever feeling that it is getting you down too much or that you are too stressed, please do not hesitate to see a doctor, your health is far more important than a single job.

**Saying No**

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, regarding employment law and the bounds of your contract you should definitely contact an employment lawyer.*

Ok so let's assume your contract does indeed say that you work from 9-5. If your supervisor insists that you **MUST** stay until all your work is completed you can say no.

However, don't be rude, always be respectful to your supervisor, even if s/he is disrespectful to you. Try not to degenerate into an argument over it, politely explain that you have commitments to maintain outside of the working environment and that your contract clearly states that you work from 9-5.

I would also hazard you to make a choice, if its only going to take an extra 5-10 minutes it might be more beneficial to just be a team player and complete the work (provided you don't have other commitments you might miss) however if it is going to take 3-4 hours extra then it might be in your best interests to decline.

**Overtime**

If you are consistently being asked to work out of hours do not do it for free. If the work will take an extra hour of your time, be sure that you make sure you are getting paid for it! If they won't pay overtime don't do the work. However, you should endeavour to explain this politely, if it degenerates into an argument it may be best for both sides to cool off.

**Improving your workflow**

An alternative method might be how to best complete as much work as you can in a given day to minimise any extra time you might need to be working.

If the work you are doing can be done by yourself and you aren't needed by anyone else and if your workplace allows it, you might find it beneficial to isolate yourself to ensure your workflow isn't interrupted.

This can be done by actual isolation in a separate location, or can be achieved by listening to music or white noise at your own desk. It's important to still interact with your team otherwise you will be completely isolated, which causes problems of its own.

**Conclusion**

So if you can't find a way out of this position, and you cant find a way to explain to the supervisor that what s/he is asking for is impossible / improbable then there are still things you can do to improve your working environment and to ensure that the stress doesn't get the better of you.

Comment: One thing I would recommend is to talk to your colleages about this, in a casual way. Find out if your supervisor behaves like this to all of them, and maybe find out how they handle it. You might also try to find out how much work they are given, whether it is more or less than you. If it is the same amount, and they are completing it in a normal working day, see if there is some trick you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

First check your contract. What does it explicitly say about working hours and how long you are expected to work for. Does it say you have to work late all the time? Or just certain times?

They can only hold you to the hours you agreed to in the contract. If it is not mentioned, then that needs to be discussed with them. Remember though, that any agreement needs to go into a contract, and make sure that the deadline is not changed as part of that update to the contract.

Apart from that you need to check your countries laws as to how long you can actually work. Some countries have strict laws on how much overtime you can do within a set time, even if you signed a contract otherwise.

> Is there anything I can do that will make these last few months more bearable for myself,

You have a few months left and you are free! Just count the days.

I would also recommend to start planning on what you want to do after your contract runs out. It will keep you focused and distracted from the stress.